# How to do mean square error for multivariable exponential functions?

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis

I'm trying to find the optimal solutions for a multivariable exponential function. The function is in the form as:

$y_{i}=\left ( \beta_{1}x_{i1}+\beta_{2}x_{i2} +\beta_{i3}x_{3}\right )e^{\beta_{4}x_{i4}}$

where $\beta_{1-4}$ are to-optimize parameters. I try to solve this problem by lease square as:

$argmin {\sum (Y - y_{i})}^2$

But I'm not sure how to update the gradient for this function. Linear functions are pretty easy. I tried optimize.leaseq in scipy and it works. But I want to know how internally it calculates. Thanks,

Comment: @ pingge : In addition to the comment of Claude Leibovici, can you edit an example of data in order to test a method which don't need initial guessing for $\beta_4$, nor iterative calculus.

Comment: @JJacquelin I donot have data for this problem right now. Actually I'm trying to optimize a multivariable function which as 34 $\beta$s. Just make it easier I only showed 4 $\beta$s here

Comment: Making it easier don't solve the problem. A method working well for 4 parameters might be non-convenient for 34 parameters. One have to be very cautious in case of such kind of fitting problems. I never propose a method without checking if the method is convenient for the particular problem considered. On a general viewpoint, 34 parameters to adjust is  a big number which requires very large experimental data, especially if they are scattered. Good luck !

Comment: How many exponential terms are present in the 34 terms ? If only one, what I wrote would work. Even with 2 or 3, we could do something.

Comment: @JJacquelin. I was sure to meet you here today ! *Bien le bonjour !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Assuming that you have data points $(x_{1i},x_{2i},x_{3i},x_{4i},y_i)$ and the model $$y=\left ( \beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2} +\beta_{3}x_{3}\right )e^{\beta_{4}x_{4}}$$ I should fix $\beta_{4}$ at a given value and define $z_i=e^{\beta_{4}x_{4i}}$ making the model linear with respect to the remaining parameters.

So, for a given value of $\beta_{4}$, we can get the other $( \beta_{1},\beta_{2},\beta_{3})$ and the corresponding objective function (whatever it could be). Now, try different values of $\beta_{4}$ until you see an area where a minimum seems to happen for the objective function. At this point, you have all elements for starting the full process.

I must confess that I am thinking more about nonlinear regression than about any other method.

Comment: Thank you very much! This should work just wondering if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: @pingge. I strongly suggest you look at the method JJacquelin propose (look at his answers on the site). What you could do it to provide us a set of data (as he has been asking) for **this** model and ask him to apply the method for you. The big advantage of the method he promotes is that you don't need initial estimates.